# Web SQL Database persistence on iOS 5.1

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, web-sql

I have read [several](http://www.itwriting.com/blog/5656-apple-breaks-web-storage-in-ios-5-1-does-not-care-about-web-apps.html) [accounts](http://www.sencha.com/blog/html5-scorecard-the-new-ipad-and-ios-5-1) of degraded persistence of Web SQL Databases created from embedded UIWebViews in iOS 5.1, but I am having trouble determining whether this issue also exists for web applications visited in plain old Mobile Safari. Does anyone know if I should expect lower levels of data persistence for web applications accessed with Mobile Safari?

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm still not completely sure that web apps accessed with Mobile Safari are immune to this issue, the following fix for this issue in the [iOS 6.0 Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html) seems to imploy that the problem was specific to native apps with embedded UIWebViews:

> In iOS 6 and later, web data (SQL Web Storage and LocalStorage) from a UIWebView object can be stored in a directory that will be backed up. To enable backing up this data, set the WebKitStoreWebDataForBackup key to YES in your app’s user defaults. This should be done only if your app relies on web content data that cannot be reloaded. If your UIWebView object opens links to arbitrary web content, this key should be set to NO. Toggling the value of this key will not preserve existing web view data.